# Why I can't use same animation for border-left?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a hover effect with border-left that starts from center...
After searcher in the web I could only find how to do underline

```css
ul.sub_menu li a:after {
 display:block;
   content: '';
   border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
   transform: scaleX(0.0001);  
   transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
ul.sub_menu li a:hover:after {
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
 <ul class="list-unstyled sub_menu" role="tablist">
    
    <li  role="presentation" class="active">
<a href="#head" ria-controls="header" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Header</a></li>
    
    <li  role="presentation">
<a href="#about" aria-controls="about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
```

when I try to change `scaleX` to `Y` and `border-left` I get no results at all, no border...
Maybe I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: can you explain better what is the goal here? I didnt get the objective that youre trying to achieve; You mean the same current example, but working with border-left instead of border-bottom?

Comment: I'm trying to have the same animation as in the menu of this https://ui8.net/categories/ui-kits when hover over the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a left border, first you have to switch to `:before` and not `:after`. Then you need to set a height for the element so that it can actually have a border. Otherwise content is empty and size is empty. So you can do this:

```css
ul.sub_menu li a:before {
    display:inline-block;
    content: '';
    border-left: solid 3px #019fb6;  
    transform: scaleY(0.001);  
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    height:1em;
}
ul.sub_menu li a:hover:before {
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled sub_menu" role="tablist">

    <li  role="presentation" class="active">
<a href="#head" ria-controls="header" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Header</a></li>

    <li  role="presentation">
<a href="#about" aria-controls="about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
```